# nand2tetris 16bit PC using 8bit registers

Tags: nand2tetris

I have been asked to make a 16bit PC from the nand2tetris course using 2 8bit registers instead of 1 16bit one. I need to get these 2 8bit registers to function as 1 16bit register.I cant seem to get it to work, any help would be much appriciated.

Register(in=cout,  out=out[0..7],  out=feedback,  load=true);

Register(in=cout, out=out[8..15], out=feedback, load=true);

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how your 8 bit register works, it is difficult to be sure, but I notice two things:

1. It is unclear what feedback does, or why you need it, but you're just tying the output of the two 8 bit registers together.
2. You are not specifying what bits of cout are going to the input bits of each register. Also, its confusing that the input bits for your composite register are called cout.